# Can't initialize Parse SDK Test

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform, android-studio-2.0

**When I try to run the app to test if my SDK is installed I get**

Error:(35, 22) error: no suitable method found for initialize(,String,String)
method Parse.initialize(Context,String,String) is not applicable
(actual argument  cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
method Parse.initialize(Context) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

I followed all the instructions as well as checked numerous tutorials on how to do it but still get this error.

Source code:

```
package com.dusanp.passer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();

            Parse.initialize(this, "zHpYwtZUDEHFuDULv2Vwt9rR0fie7fANFx7s24hT", "trnAIEthNLKkT6ueBP0ATYZh6pYhbpXFTN2gsSbP");

            ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
            testObject.put("foo", "bar");
            testObject.saveInBackground();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: Source code, please?

Comment: I am sorry, I'm new to this. I need to copy the code where the error is located? @SteveCohen

Comment: Yes, otherwise no one can help you.  You still haven't shown FULL source code.  LIke import statements.  What is Parse? is it imported from somewhere?  Where?  What is the signature for the Parse.initialize() method?   What is AppCompatActiivty?

Comment: Is it OK now?@SteveCohen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line

```
Parse.initialize(this, "zHpYwtZUDEHFuDULv2Vwt9rR0fie7fANFx7s24hT", "trnAIEthNLKkT6ueBP0ATYZh6pYhbpXFTN2gsSbP");
```

Inside your onClickListener `this` refers to the click listener and not a Context which is what the Pase sdk is expecting for that parameter.
If the name of your Activity is MainActivity then the line would look like the below.

```
Parse.initialize(MainActivity.this, "zHpYwtZUDEHFuDULv2Vwt9rR0fie7fANFx7s24hT", "trnAIEthNLKkT6ueBP0ATYZh6pYhbpXFTN2gsSbP");
```

Comment: Thank you @IvanWooll But now i have this error: 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: What happens if you take that line outside of the onClick method? I.E. above if.

Comment: Ah ok, Didn't see that error message until I refreshed the page. Did you Google that error message?

Comment: I googled it. Something with multidex libraries is the solution. Should I do that?

Comment: I found a solution it was to clean the project